# Android - Device screen flips even if the application screen orientation is set to Landscape when Auto Rotate is ON

Tags: android, performance, xamarin, xamarin.android, screen-orientation

In my activity, I have the following code.

```
[Activity(Label = "SampleActivity", ConfigurationChanges = Android.Content.PM.ConfigChanges.Orientation | Android.Content.PM.ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | Android.Content.PM.ConfigChanges.KeyboardHidden)]
```

In OnCreate() ->

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Gingerbread) {
                RequestedOrientation = ScreenOrientation.SensorLandscape;
            }
            else {
                RequestedOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Landscape;
            }
```

Still the screen flips in landscape mode itself if the **Auto rotate is ON**.Would like to know the reason why this happens?.Is there any option to avoid flipping?

Need help.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In order to lock your app in portrait mode, You have to add following line in your manifest file where you are defining your activity in the manifest file.

```
 <activity android:name=".yourActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
```

If you want to lock in landscape mode replace portrait with landscape.

Comment: The above code what I have added is in Xamarin. So, I have added in Activity. Thanks.

Comment: u r welcome @sha , u can accept my answer if you like :)

Answer (score 0):

Try writing this in `Menifest` file:

```
<activity
            android:name="SampleActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape" // or "portrait" if you want
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />
```

For Xamarin change your code according to your need as: **(ScreenOrientation.Portrait / ScreenOrientation.Landscape)**

```
[Activity(Label = "SampleActivity", ConfigurationChanges = Android.Content.PM.ConfigChanges.Orientation | Android.Content.PM.ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | Android.Content.PM.ConfigChanges.KeyboardHidden),ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait)]
```

Comment: I need to add them in Activity not manifest in Xamarin. I will try adding screenLayout and update you on that. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, you may get your problem resolved after adding that